# Custom Asset Compilation in Play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Out of the box Play 2.0 support LESS and CoffeeScript asset compilatio, for example,

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/AssetsCoffeeScript

I was wondering if there was a simple, clean way to provide custom asset compilers without having to define your own controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question.  It is possible to add you own compilers by adding new ones to the `Build.scala` file in your project.  e.g.

```
resourceGenerators in Compile <+= MyNewResourceCompilerCompiler
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/rnz9mrejtj8